# How to add a GIT submodule for VSTS for use with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, azure, visual-studio-2017

How do I create a submodule repo and my another project that is C#, MVC in it's own repo both in Azure GIT and use that or reference it in the Visual Studio 2017 IDE?

Is there any videos that show this or documentation that explains this? I'm not seeing anything and especially with Visual Studio.  Maybe I'm not looking in the right place.

I know there is a reference to [Workflow for using git submodules in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951252/workflow-for-using-git-submodules-in-visual-studio)

Is creating a GIT repo of the shared/common code and then adding it as another project?

What is it's just a like a shared dll or set of shared DLL's that are in the submodule repo. They needed to be added a reference in the other project.

As you can see I am a newbie to GIT.

Any info is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, try and add your common Git repo to your current coding Git repo through command line, with [`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt), as [shown here](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/).

Then check you have at least [Visual Studio 2017 update 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.5#teamexplorer)

> You can now work with Git submodules and worktrees, and configure `fetch.prune` and `pull.rebase` in Team Explorer.
>   Visual Studio now treats Git submodules and worktrees like normal repos. Just add them to your list of Local Repositories and get coding!
>
> Please note that for submodules, you still cannot do any action that requires multi-repo support (such as viewing a file in the parent repo and a file in the submodule at the same time). ([vote here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/351156/allow-multiple-git-repositories-to-be-active-at-on.html))